# Kubectl Commands

Tags: linux, kubernetes, devops, kubectl

I have a k8s cluster running in oracle cloud oci and we have kubectl client running in one of the vm and this VM has got the kubeconfig file also. All of a sudden we see that "kubectl get pods -A" , "kubectl version --short" I mean nothing works with kubectl command and I have to restart the machine, anybody facing the same issue?

kubectl client version is 1.21

CPU and memory usage is very minimum

Comment: Did you check kubelet logs? Also kubelet status, if you are using `systemctl` you can do a `systectl status kubelet` to see its current status.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70379189/edit) and say what "nothing works" means in your case -- it times out? it displays a TLS error? it prints in pig latin? Be sure to read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for getting the most benefit from the Stack Exchange network. Good luck

Comment: What I mean with nothing works is, any kubectl command you execute through a particular machine it just stucks and there's no error with the command output infact there is no command output the command just stays there and we waited for almost 2 hrs for the command to be executed, we also did "kubectl commands --v=6" but when we try to execute the kubectl commands from any other machine it does work, can it be something to do with "tcp_mem"?